# Magento 1.9.1 - Swatch Size Selection Displays Wrong Main Image

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

Can anyone help me understand why when I select a size for the second colour version of a product it shows the first products colour image unless I reselect the colour again. Although the right colour attribute label is shown and the right colour size combination is added to basket?
I have reinstalled from start all files and a new database. I can set up the first product ok. After that, doing nothing different, I am unable to construct a probably working configurable product.
The product has its two colour images version loaded each with its label matching the correct attribute colour(lower-case) with the first set to default. The only other selectable attribute is size.
It seems that if I select size from the second colour it "falls back" to the base default image(wrong). 
I know I can get around this by adding the correct image to each and every simple size variant of that colour. But that seems a hack to me as I know it can work without the need to assign a individual size variant per simple product size.
http://www.clickmasters.co.uk/womens-boots.html
As shown the first products works as expected(emu) Fly does not

*** FIXED THIS BIT***
Also wrong image is used in basket.***
System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart > Configurable Product Image = Product Thumbnail Itself